# Scanf doesn't work well with while loop

Tags: c, console, scanf

So I have the following code:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int loggedIn=0;
    char *currentCommand;

    while (!loggedIn)
    {
    printf("Enter your command:");
    scanf("%s",currentCommand);
    printf("\n%s\n",currentCommand);
    }
}
```

The problem is `scanf()` works well the first time, then is starts reading `(null)` and the output would be `Enter your command: (null)` in an infinite loop.

I want to input more commands and stop when I change the value of loggedIn, but once I input one command, it starts printing `Enter your command: (null)` endlesly.

Comment: You have not allocated any space for `currentCommand`

Comment: Yes, it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate memory to the **currentCommand** pointer with **malloc** (and free it at the end) or give a size to it in the beginning, like

```
char currentCommand[256];
```

Comment: Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

currentCommand is pointer variable who will save address(which is integer) of char type variable and have a size of 4 bytes (32 bit machine).

Now when you write ℅s in scanf you are supposed to pass address of char array.(which you haven't declared), so scanf will take the address (value saved in currentCommand which is garbage).

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing while using character pointers is you can create a character array at the time of declaration i.e.,

```
char *p="Hello World";
```

This creates memory in data/code section which is read only section.

And you cannot create a character array with `scanf()` function.
Should have to use dynamic memory allocation or initialize as above